# Fitting brake cables on Tektro rl726 levers

Tags: brakes

Iv'e got some Tektro RL726 brake levers that I want to fit to a project bike.  I bought the cables online & they have arrived with a stopper on both ends.  Am I right in thinking I have to cut one end off so I can thread it all through the brake, lever & housing?

If I have to cut the cable, which end do i keep for that lever type? The bigger drum bit or the more torpedo like narrower stopper (which looks like it would fit in the housing of the lever a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to cut off the stopper you don't need.

In your case, cut the non-torpedo end. Take a look at the picture here: http://www.tektro.com/_english/01_products/01_prodetail.php?pid=58&sortname=Lever&sort=1&fid=3

Under "Specifications", "Brake Cable Type" it has a picture of the end you need to leave attached.

Happy Riding!